# Create Role via MS CRM 4.0 SDK v.4.0.12

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I got "last" version of MS CRM 4.0 SDK - 4.0.12.
And now I want to create some custom role via new SDK stuff: "CrmDataContext".

Starting with this:

```
var ctx = new CmsDataServiceDataContext();
var r = new role
     {
       roleid = new Guid("F263E5F9-97FA-4B4C-BF46-47795DE7263F"),
       name = "Role Test",
       businessunitid = new Guid("E7BE33F4-31D4-DF11-9B76-080027602153"),
     };
ctx.AddToroles(r);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

And... that's ALL!

I can't attach privileges to this role, because could not find any mechanism to link privileges to role.

I got roleprivileges class with roleid and privilegeid properties, but they are read only.

I read [this article about custom role creating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151187.aspx) and Request/Response model is greats, but how to do the same stuff with new SDK I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The XRM thing does not replicate/replace everything that is possible in "classic" SDK development. I haven't used it with CRM 4, but with the CRM 2011 pre-release stuff, as soon as there were special Request classes beyond the standard web service messages involved, I had to use those through an `IOrganizationService` object.

The XRM classes make much of the everyday data manipulation easier and nicer to handle (especially when one wasn't using another code generator such as Stunnware Tools already), but for anything a little more special, it looks like `CrmService.Execute()` (or `IOrganizationService.Execute()` in 2011) isn't going anywhere.